# How to send a success message from MVC controller to Ajax after the controller has inserted parameters Ajax passed to into SQL Server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

JavaScript:

```js
$("#button").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controller/SaveSelection",
        data: {
            "Date": "date",
            "DataType": "type",
            "Id": "1234",
            "Name": "name"
        },
        success:function(){
            alert("Your selections have been saved");//never returned
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failed");//always return this one, even it's succeed
        }
    });
});
```

C# Controller:

```c#
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveSelection(Mytable obj) 
{
    try
    {
        _dataContext.Mytable.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }

    return View();
}
```

The controller can successfully insert the AJAX parameters into a SQL Server table. But in the frontend returns 500, apparently because I'm not requiring a data callback.

But is there a way to let the controller tell the JS that "Hey, I have successfully inserted those data you passed to me" so that the JS can return a success message in the browser?

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means your throwing an exception

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: `return Json("your success message",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` this line returns a success mesage. You can use it with this method: `success:function(data){ alert(data);}`

Comment: 500 does not make sense as a return, especially with you swallowing the exception like that.  Maybe there's no View for "SaveSelection"?

Comment: Thanks y'all. you are helping me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying changing your method to an actionResult or JsonResult:

```
    public ActionResult SaveSelection(Mytable obj)
    {
        try 
        {
          ....logic here....
          return Json("Your selections have been saved.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: log exception
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

As dave pointed out, you could also return like this instead:

```
return Content(jsonObject.ToString(), "application/json");
```

or

```
return Content("Your message",...
```

Then in your ajax call change the success to:

```
success: function(json) {
     alert(json);
}
error: function (event) {
            alert(event.statusText);
        }
```

Comment: If you just want to return a string, you can use `Controller.Content()` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470588(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.